# How do I customize llbd for Xcode projects

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm, lldb

Currently, I am using Xcode to develop iOS projects. How can I customize the lldb environment for my project?

I created a. ldbinit file in the project folder, which contains the following settings:

Settings set target. executable search paths/Users/xxx/Desktop/lldb/llvm project/lldb_ Xcode/Debug/bin/lldb

Set debugger "/Users/xxx/Desktop/lldb/llvm project/lldb_xcode/Debug/bin/lldb"

But it didn't take effect, and in the end, the Xcode Launch log displayed:

Using LLDBRPC, LLDB framework is from/Applications/Xcode14.2.app/Content/SharedFrameworks

Answer (score 0):

lldb itself has two places it will look for startup scripts, in the user's home directory (~/.lldbinit) and in the CWD of the debugger.  The latter is off by default for security reasons, but is also not all that helpful for GUI apps, where you don't really know where the CWD is (and is usually something not helpful like `/`.)

lldb supports another convention that's useful in this context. If the lldb framework is running in an app called, for instance `Xcode`, then if there's a startup file in the user's home directory called: `~/.lldbinit-Xcode` that will be read in preference to `~/.lldbinit`.  That way you can customize lldb differently for command-line and Xcode usage.

Finally, starting several versions ago, Xcode added support for Target specific lldb startup files.  If you edit the Run Scheme of your Xcode target, in the Info tab there's an entry for LLDB Init File.  If you put the path to your lldbinit file there (it can be relative to the project using `$(SRCROOT)` to indicate the project source location) Xcode will use that in preference to the others when running that particular target.

Comment: Thank you so much

You are right. I also learned about the difference between ~/.lldbinit-Xcode and ~/.lldbinit before;

Comment: Yes, I am also currently modifying the LLDB Init File of Xcode Target, and it seems that the Log is now effective;
The Xcode Launch Log will show:
Using custom lldb init file: /Users/xxxx/Desktop/lldb/slowDebugTest-main

I feel that my current operation is correct. I guess there is something wrong with writing the content of my .lldbinit file:
A syntax error occurred between settings set target.executable-search-paths and set debugger

Comment: I would like to ask how I should write to replace it with the lldb compiled by myself (currently I use LLVM source code to compile the lldb executable file)

Comment: The officially supported way to do that is to build a "swift toolchain", install it in /Library/Developer/Toolchains and select it using the Xcode->Toolchains menu.  The swift site has information about how to build a toolchain from the swift/clang/llvm/lldb sources.

Comment: As for script errors, try typing them in one by one into a live debug session to see the errors more easily?  One thing to note, though you can use the Xcode variables (like `$(SRCROOT)` in the path specification in the Xcode Run scheme, you can't use them in the LLDB init script itself.  Those are Xcode variables, lldb doesn't know about them, and Xcode doesn't have a precompiler stage for lldb scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the swift toolchain should be able to meet my needs. I will give it a try; Thank you again